# Shiny: 'data' must be 2-dimensional error when trying to update values inside renderDT

Tags: r, shiny, file-io

I am learning RShiny where I am trying to import a xlsx file using fileInput and then execute a series of data cleaning steps such as removing unecessary columns and ensuring consistency in naming convention prior to displaying the data using renderDT. I can import the file. Delete a column just like I would in R for a data frame, but when I try to replace a entry with an updated name I get the following error. "Warning: Error in : 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)" I tried assuming the Shiny is treating the imported file as a list instead of a data frame, also tried using as.data.frame but completely striking out. could use some help understanding what type of object mydata is stored as. As well as how to properly update a value in mydata. In the example below I am trying to replace values "Old Name" in columns B with "New Name" and remove the third column C. Code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
require(DT)

mydata <- structure(list(
  A = c(2, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8),
  B = c("A", "Old Name",
        "N", "Old Name", "L", "L"),
  C = c(1, 3, 5, 2, 2, 2)
),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA,
              -6L))

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Load Data"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx formatted file',
                    accept = c(".xlsx")
          )
        ),
        mainPanel(
          DTOutput('contents'))
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output){
      
      
       output$contents <- renderDT({
         req(input$file1)
         
         inFile <- input$file1
         mydata<-read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
         mydata<-mydata[,-3]
         # Code works fine until here where it kicks an error saying its not a 2 dimensional data frame or matrix.
         mydata$B[mydata$B=="Old Name"]<-"New Name"
              
      })
       
      
    }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it may be best to do data wrangling in a `reactive` object, and then just display the data.  Try this

```
server = function(input, output){
      
      mydf <- reactive({
        req(input$file1)
        
        inFile <- input$file1
        mydata<-read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
        mydata<-mydata[,-3]
        # Code works fine until here where it kicks an error saying its not a 2 dimensional data frame or matrix.
        mydata$B[mydata$B=="Old Name"]<-"New Name"
        mydata
      })
      
      output$contents <- renderDT({
        mydf()
      })
      
    }
```

[image: output]

Comment: Separating data wrangling from visualisation (and acquisition) is always a good idea.  The problem with OP's code may be that the assignment in the final line of the `renderDT` means that `renderDT` is attempting to render a `NULL`.